# fb_graph post on a facebook group as a group member from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

Currently, I've a rails app. If user is authenticated with `facebook` then he can post something on my application. After the post was saved, my rails app will post the user's  post to my facebook group. Is it possible?

I'm using [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) gem. And after the user's post I've done a `after_create` callback to post on facebook. Here is the callback code:

```
def post_story_to_facebook
    if self.user.authentications.pluck(:provider).include?('facebook')
      page = FbGraph::Group.new('ct.dhk.group') # group name 
      # where should I declare the user who is posting? 
      page.feed!(
          :message => 'Updating via FbGraph',
          :link => 'https://domain.tld',
          :name => 'PageName',
          :description => 'This is a test post to be deleted'
      )
    end
  end
```

The above method is not working and I don't know how can I post behalf of the user?

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar working tested code. You need to store the `facebook_user_access_token` in your User model (if you don't have one, add a new attribute, and update that every time the user gets authenticated through OAuth, or only if token is renewed). See the following.

```
post = Post.find(1) # your post
facebook_page_id = '1234567890' # your Facebook group id
facebook_user_access_token = current_user.facebook_user_access_token # the current user's Facebook user access token

page = FbGraph::Page.new(facebook_page_id)
facebook_page_access_token = page.get_access_token(access_token: facebook_user_access_token)

me = FbGraph::User.me(facebook_page_access_token)

me.feed!(
  message: post.title,
  link: post_url(post),
  description: post.content,
  picture: post.main_image.url
)
```

**UPDATE:**

Haven't tested, but looking at [this](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph#user-content-post) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed)

suggests that the following could work:

```
group = FbGraph::Group.new(GROUP_ID)
group.feed!({
  access_token: USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_WITH_PROPER_PERMISSIONS,
  message: post.content
})
```

Unfortunately, I do not yet have the time to test things out. Can you try if this will work?

Comment: Group doesn't have any attribute llike `access_token` that's why it is throwing error: `OAuthException :: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (access_token) on node type (Group)`

Comment: @Emu, updated my answer. Can you try if it will work?

Comment: What do you mean by `USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_WITH_PROPER_PERMISSIONS`? New error is `The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`. So, what permissions should I enable?

Comment: @Emu, from the [second link in my answer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed), it seems both `user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions` are needed